# GWT remote logging with custom handler

Tags: java, .net, gwt

I am writing a GWT client that communicates using REST/Json with .NET services running on IIS.

I have experience using GWT with Java servlets and normal RPC and I know it is possible to send Logger.log output to the remote java server by specifying

```xml
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />
```

in the .gwt.xml module file. And by configuring the servlet in the web.xml file.

I know that this SimpleRemoteHandler uses GWT/RPC for communication.
Now my question is, can I write my own RemoteHandler for storing messages on the server, that doesn't use GWT/RPC but just REST/JSON using RequestBuilder ?

A getting started guide of how to do this with a normal Java Servlet or a PHP page, should also be a big help to see which way I have to go to develop this in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is the following :

Just create a class that extends RemoteLogHandlerBase and do the stuff you want to do in the publish method you have to override.

```
package be.gps.gwt.client.log;

import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

import com.google.gwt.logging.client.RemoteLogHandlerBase;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;

public class JsonRemoteLogHandler extends RemoteLogHandlerBase
{
   // =============================================================================================
   /**
    * Constructor.
    */
   public JsonRemoteLogHandler()
   {

   }

   // =============================================================================================
   @Override
   public void publish(LogRecord logRecord)
   {
      Window.alert("publish " + logRecord.getMessage());

      //TODO send to server
   }
}
```

Then you have to configure this loghandler in your module .gwt.xml like :

```
<replace-with class="be.gps.gwt.client.log.JsonRemoteLogHandler">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.logging.client.SimpleRemoteLogHandler" />
    <any>
      <when-property-is name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
      <when-property-is name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />
    </any>
</replace-with>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can consume a Rest Service in GWT using RequestBuilder.

Create your Rest Service in .Net and consume it in GWT application.

References:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor

---

Steps to be followed:

1. Remove the simpleRemoteHandler
2. Collect the events to be logged
3. Invoke the Rest service with the log

   **A sample approach**

   2.1.  Create a Super class for Events and let all your events extends this     class

   2.2. If an event is fired before calling gwt's fireEvent, note down the logging information in a Map

   2.3. Once the map reaches a desired counts, say 20 events, trigger your rest call to the API which you have written in .NET (use RequestBuilder in gwt to invoke the service)

   or

   You can have a scheduler which runs on desired interval

   2.4. Clear the Map.

Comment: I am aware of all this.

I want to know how I can send my logs to the server, using another system than the simpleRemoteHandler which is delivered with GWT.

This because the simpleRemoteHandler works against a java servlet, and I don't have a servlet container.

Comment: capture your logs in json format and hit the rest service in .Net with the logs, does it helps?

Comment: I have updated the answer with additional steps, hope it helps

Comment: I think I will have to dig in the source of SimpleRemoteHandler to see how it works.

What I really want to know, how this SimpleRemoteHandler takes care of the fact that if you do a java.util.Logger.log(), this is send to the server.